# J: Applying two arguments to a monadic verb produces strange results

Tags: j

I was wondering what would happen if I apply two arguments to this verb: `3&*`.
If the left one is `1` all works as if it was only one argument:

```
   1 (3&*) 3
9
   1 (3&*) 4
12
   1 (3&*) 5
15
```

If I change it I discover why that worked:

```
   2 (3&*) 5
45
   3 (3&*) 5
135
   10 (3&*) 5
295245
```

It seems that the left argument is interpreted as a repetition like `^:`. So the last one is equal to `3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 5` (10 3's), or:

```
   5 * 3^10
295245
```

Can you explain this weird behavior? I was expecting something like `domain error` (which is ubiquitous), and that is thrown if I try to use fndisplay:

```
   require 'j/addons/general/misc/fndisplay.ijs'
   defverbs 'f'
   defnouns 'x y n'
   x (n&*) y
|domain error
|   x    (n&*)y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is documented.

> x m&v y ↔ m&v^:x y
>
> x u&n y ↔ u&n^:x y

[&Bond from J dictionary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d630n.htm)

Comment: Damn, how can I have missed it?! I read the dictionary entry about `&` just before asking. Thank you for pointing it out! :)